# Publishing to the Microsoft Store?

Tags: maui, microsoft-store

I am having all kinds of trouble publishing my MAUI app to the Microsoft Store.

1. If I try publishing from Visual Studio, I get the following error:

- "You must publish one version of this application to the Microsoft Store before using the Store submission automation tool"

2. If I try to upload the package manually to the Microsoft Store (i.e. in a package submission), I get the following errors:

- "Invalid package family name: XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXX_6k51yetae26ce (expected: XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXX_t7g5vnbs3ke9w)" - but I have no control over the suffix that gets added. Where/how do I change that?
- "Declared package dependency unavailable: Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.1.2, Neutral, Universal,Universal" - how do I fix this? Can I include it as a dependency somehow?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT I'm sure you meant to be helpful, but to me that answer looks like you're just trying to accumulate points.  It doesn't address the problems I'm experiencing.  The problems above happen after following the directions in that document!

Comment: I found https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/18571. The workaround there is: manually set Version in Package.appxmanifest instead of 0.0.0.0. Not sure if helpful here. If not, my bad.